# Write a file based on axios response

Tags: node.js, axios, filesystems

I am making a request to a endpoint using axios.
Then, I want to get this request and save the data in a file called response.json.
The file is being created, but the content is being saved like this:

```
[object Object]
```

this is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const filesystem = require('fs');

// Make request using to the api using axios
axios.get('http://date.jsontest.com/')
    .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        filesystem.writeFile('response.json', response.data, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's up?

You have to save using `JSON.stringify(response.data)` instead of only `response.data`

Answer (score 0):

```
    const axios = require('axios');
const filesystem = require('fs');

// Use array buffer! 

axios.get('http://date.jsontest.com/',{ responseType:"arraybuffer"})
    .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        filesystem.writeFile('response.json', response.data, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```